# Cassandra: copy from Row to BoundStatement

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm trying to write a generic tool for copying Cassandra table contents from one keyspace to another one (probably in a different cluster). All the tables are not too large.

Here is what I do:

```
Session source = ...
Session destination = ...
TableMetadata table = ...

final ResultSet rs = source.execute("select * from " + table.getName());
String insertCql = ...
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = destination.prepare(insertCql);

for (Row row : rs) {
    final BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind();

    for (int i = 0; i < rs.getColumnDefinitions().size(); i++) {
        // bind column value from row to bountStatement
    }

    session.execute(boundStatement);
}
```

The problem is how to copy the column value from `row` to `boundStatement`. I can read it with `row.getObject(i)`, but there is no corresponding `setObject()` in `BoundStatement`.

More precisely, this method exists in version 2.2 of the driver (it's `cassandra-driver-dse`), but that version does not work with Cassandra 3, and in version 3 of the driver (`cassandra-driver-core`) `setObject()` method does not exist. Instead, there are bunch of `set()` methods, all of them require `Class`, `TypeToken` or `TypeCodec`.

Where can I get those? `ColumnDefinition` only gives me `DataType`. It seems a doubtful idea to use `row.getObject(i).getClass()` to get `Class`.

Maybe there is a better approach to this task (schema-agnostic copying)?

I can look at `DataType` if the column and make a case per type to use `setString()` and so on, but this seems a bit overcomplicated and fragile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use bind variables in your insert statement and then bind the prepared statement with the column values from the result. Something along the lines of:

```
String insertCql = "INSERT INTO ks.tb (...) values (?,?,...)";
for (Row row : rs) {
    List bindVariables = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < rs.getColumnDefinitions().size(); i++) {
        bindVariables.add(rs.getObject(i));
    }
    final BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind(bindVariables.toArray(new Object[0]));
    session.execute(boundStatement);
}
```

Comment: I also tried `set()` method with `TypeCodec` obtained via `preparedStatement.getCodecRegistry().codecFor(col.getType())`, but it caused some problem with `timeuuid`/`uuid` incompatibility. At the same time, your approach works great. Thank you!